# Problem using ChatterBot in Python: AttributeError 'time' has no attribute 'clock'

Tags: python, chatterbot

I have this code using the `chatterbot` third-party library:

```
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer
import time
from time import perf_counter

# Import the chatterbot module
import chatterbot

# Create a ChatBot instance with the name
chatbotj = chatterbot.ChatBot('epicurus')

# Create an instance of the ChatterBotCorpusTrainer
trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(chatbotj)

# Train the chatbot using the Italian corpus
trainer.train('chatterbot.corpus.italian')

exit_conditions = (":q", "quit", "exit")
while True:
     query = input("> ")
     if query in exit_conditions:
         break
     else:
         response = chatbotj.get_response(query)
         print(response)
```

When I try using the code, I get an error like this from Visual Studio:

```
   Message=module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'
   Source=C:\Users\User\source\repos\PythonApplication5\PythonApplication5\PythonApplication5.py
   Stack Trace:
   File "C:\Users\User\source\repos\PythonApplication5\PythonApplication5\PythonApplication5.py", line 9, in <module> (Current frame)
     chatbotj = chatterbot.ChatBot('epicurus')
AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'
```

I have these packages installed:

```
ChatterBot==1.0.4
chatterbot-corpus==1.2.0
click==8.1.7
colorama==0.4.6
joblib==1.3.2
mathparse==0.1.2
nltk==3.8.1
Pint==0.22
pymongo==3.13.0
python-dateutil==2.7.5
pytz==2023.3.post1
PyYAML==3.13
regex==2023.8.8
six==1.16.0
SQLAlchemy==1.2.19
tqdm==4.66.1
typing_extensions==4.7.1
```

I tried both with Python 3.9 and 3.11 and with Chatterbot 1.0.5, installing all the individual packages separately after using `--install --no-deps` (because I had problems using `pip install chatterbot --upgrade`).

What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is definitely not a complete stack trace. Please show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/) error message by **copying and pasting, starting from the first line you can find** that says `Traceback (most recent call last):`, **all the way to the end**, and formatting it the same way as the code. If you don't see such a line, use the command line to run the code instead of your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You're using an old version of sqlalchemy that relies on the now deprecated `time.clock`. See [requirements.txt](https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/blob/master/requirements.txt). Try updating it

```
pip install sqlalchemy --upgrade
```